# How to make an object of another class act on an object of another class in c++?

Tags: c++, class

Even though these are my first activities to learn classes, we already dealing with multiple files so I am struggling to do what the task is asking me to.

Activity 7 goes like this:
 Create a new Class for a CarMechanic.
CarMechanic.h, CarMechanic.cpp

The CarMechanic should have an attribute for:
string name;

The CarMechanic class should have methods for:
CarMechanic(string name); // constructor
void repairCar(Car carToFix);
Inside the repairCar method, it should call the repair method on the Car object that was passed in as a parameter.

Test in main by creating a CarMechanic object and repairing a Car.

So I tried to do this.
This is my CarMechanic.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;
class CarMechanic
{
private: 
bool brokenDown = false;
string name;
public:
CarMechanic(string name); //constructor
~CarMechanic();
void repairCar(Car carToFix);
void repairNow();
};
```

This is my CarMechanic.cpp file:

```
#include "CarMechanic.h"
#include <iostream>

CarMechanic::CarMechanic(string name)
{}

CarMechanic::~CarMechanic() {} //destructor does nothing

void CarMechanic::repairNow()
{
brokenDown = false;             //Car is not broken
std::cout << "The repairNow function has set car to not broken." << 
std::endl;
}

void CarMechanic::repairCar(Car carToFix)
{
repairNow();
}
```

Now I have my main.cpp file trying to use a previous object of class car I created:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"
#include "CarMechanic.h"

int main()
{
Car myCarObject1;

Car speedster(10);

CarMechanic repairMan("Mike");

repairMan.repairCar(MyCarObject1);
```

So the last line I feel should accept MyCarObject1 as the car object that Mike will repair, but it is not doing that.Visual Basic is telling me myCarObject1 is undefined, and so is Speedster. How do I get the repairCar function to take in a car object and repair it?

If this is of any help, here are my other files:

Car.h:

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

class Car
{ // defining the Car class
private: // restricted access, can only access from inside the class.
unsigned fuelLeft; // class member variable.
bool brokenDown = false;
public: // open access, can access from outside the class (e.g. main).

Car(); // default constructor, has no input parameters.
Car(unsigned); // another constructor, has unsigned as a parameter.
~Car(); // destructor, called when car objects are destroyed.

short unsigned int fuelSpace;

void drive(); // class member function.
bool hasFuel(); // class member function.
void refuel();  
void breakdownNow();
void repairNow();
bool isBrokenDown();

};

#endif // CAR_H
```

Car.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"

Car::Car() {  // defining default constructor.
fuelLeft = 5; // typical to initialise class member variables.
fuelSpace = fuelLeft;   //store the amount of fuel each car has
}

Car::Car(unsigned startingFuel) { // defining another constructor.
fuelLeft = startingFuel; // typical to initialise class member variables.
fuelSpace = startingFuel;       //store the amount of fuel each car has
}

Car::~Car() { } // destructor does nothing.

 void Car::drive() { // defining a class member function (method).


    if (brokenDown == true)         //check if car is broken first
    {
        std::cout << "Can't drive car, it has broken down!" << std::endl;
    }

    else if (fuelLeft > 0)
    {
        fuelLeft--;
        std::cout << "Drives car 1km" << std::endl;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Can't drive car, ran out of fuel!" << std::endl;
    }
}

bool Car::hasFuel() { // defining a class member function (method).
if (fuelLeft > 0 && brokenDown != true)     
    return true;
return false;
}

void Car::refuel() {
fuelLeft = fuelSpace;           
}

void Car::breakdownNow()
{
brokenDown = true;              //Car is broken
std::cout << "The beakdownNow function has set car to broken." << std::endl;
}

void Car::repairNow()
{
brokenDown = false;             //Car is not broken
std::cout << "The repairNow function has set car to not broken." << 
std::endl;
}

bool Car::isBrokenDown()
{
if (brokenDown == true)
{
    std::cout << "The car is broken." << std::endl;
    return true;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "The car isn't broken." << std::endl;
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: your `Car` is called `myCarObject1` not `MyCarObject1`

Comment: "Visual Basic is telling me" well there's one of your problems :)

Comment: btw your mechanics repair function should take the car by reference. Currently it is like when you bring your car to the workshop they will make a copy and fix the copy...not very useful ;)

Comment: there is more things fishy in your code. You might be able to get help if you can break it down to few lines of code like two classes with only a single method each. See also: [mcve]

Comment: I feel very stupid right now. Might be just too frustrated. Thanks Tobi.